# How do I delete/remove a SUSE 10.3 user?

Tags: user-management, sles

I'm using Putty to connect to my Webserver. I'd like to know the command to delete a user I've set up a few days ago. Is there also a way to display all the users and their rights?

Comment: You mean you have a user set up on the *server* that you want to delete using SSH as the interface (IOW you're trying to delete a user from the command line)? What is the operating system?

Comment: Hi! The Operating System is Suse 10.3 (it's a Plesk webserver). I added a user using "useradd". Now I'd like to delete it.

Comment: This is not really a question about Putty, ssh and Webservers. Those tags could be removed. The question is "How do I delete/remove a SUSE 10.3 user?"

Comment: Retagged the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just use `userdel <username>`. if you also want to remove the home directory and mail spool of the user use `userdel -r <username>`.